# Is there any way to have division tag to have if and else?

Tags: angular

```
      <div *ngIf="isTrue" fxFlexOffset="16px" fxFlex="24px">{{ showThis }}</div>
      <div *ngIf="!isTrue" fxFlexOffset="50px" fxFlex="24px">{{ showThis }}</div>
```

I would like to change the offset based on a condition, but for that to work right now I am using two division tags, is there any way I can achieve it using one tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use property binding as follows:

```
<div [fxFlexOffset]="isTrue ? '16px' : '50px'" fxFlex="24px">{{ showThis }}</div>
```